# How to feature good questions on our StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As a moderator, I would like to pin questions for a few days to a week that are super useful to the community such as this on:

- [What is `codeSubstitutes` in the chain spec?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/what-is-codesubstitutes-in-the-chain-spec)

Is there a way to mark certain questions as featured on substrate.stackexchange.com?

Without this feature, questions that are vital and super relevant, quickly get pushed down the queue and lost, only to find themselves at the mercy of SEO.